# Auto-increment id when field is empty

Tags: database

How to avoid auto-increment in database table when field is empty (whenever i leave project_id, project_name etc, it still automatically increment the id). What should i do to avoid this ?

Comment: you wants to insert project_id manually ?

Comment: Remove the identity(auto-increment) property from the column in the database.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you talking about PK or another autogenerated field?. In Oracle you can use a trigger

Answer (score 0):

I dont think (as far as i know) auto increment can be stopped. Any insert to the table will cause the counter to increment ( hence the name auto-increment).

Say suppose you inserted a row and the auto increment value was 10. Now delete that row and insert a new row. The value 10 wont be reused.

My advise would be to be more careful while inserting values (add as many checks as required) into the database or remove the auto increment and provide a key manually - query to get max of that column, increment it by 1 and used this new value to insert to the database(not a particularly good idea especially if the database size is huge).